# How can I refresh browser page in node.js HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I want to refresh browser page in HTTP node.js server. I tried `nodemon`, but it reloaded server instead of browser. Can you tell me how can I refresh browser page every 2 seconds? Here is my server code, thanks!

```js
var http = require('http');
var port = 5000;
 
function lightSensor() {
   var data =  Math.random().toFixed(2)    
   console.log("Light sensor: " + data);  
   return data;
}
 
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});  
  res.write('{"Light sensor" : ' + lightSensor() + '}');  
  res.write('
  res.end();
}).listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:' + port);
 
process.on('SIGINT', function () { 
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done from node's side on its own. This needs to be done on the browser side. You can do it like the following:

```html
<script>
setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: I can't use <script> in my code, because it's not HTML.

Comment: @arankat — Why did you mark this answer as solving your problem then?

Comment: Because the question got closed.